# How do I use a webtest with dependency on a C# custom extraction class

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, web-testing

Application Insights on Azure lets me upload a `.webtest` file to monitor application availability. My application is a REST/JSON service, and so my `.webtest` references a custom `ExtractJSONRule` derived from the `ExtractionRule` base class to pick out and check data from the JSON response. I can upload the `.webtest` file OK, but of course, without the custom C# code for the `ExtractJSONRule`, it always fails.

Is there any way to use custom code in an Application Insights availability test?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/ by Alan Cameron Wills:

> **Q**. Can I call code from my web test?
>   **A**. No. The steps of the test must be in the .webtest file.

I have added a feature request here: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192/suggestions/9659556